# PostgreSQL creating a subtable and using with clause

Tags: postgresql, subquery, common-table-expression

I am trying to test users for a condition, then select all events of the main table that match the condition. I feel like I am doing something wrong:

```
WITH users_table AS (
    SELECT
        user_name,
        SUM (CASE WHEN ( ud.age > 20 ) THEN 1  ELSE 0 END) AS UserEvents
    FROM users_data AS ud
    GROUP BY user_name
    )
SELECT users_table.user_name FROM users_table
WHERE users_table.UserEvents > 10
;
```

That is, I want to use the with clause to make a table of all the users above the age of 20, then of that table select only use users that has more than 10 events.

For some reason I keep getting the error:

**ERROR: multiple WITH clauses not allowed. SQL state: 42601**

But I don't understand why? Also, why "multiple" with clauses...? There's only one with clause.

Best wishes,
-R

Answer (score 2):

When you are using multiple common table expressions, you can only use the `WITH` keyword once. So it should look like:

```
WITH first_cte AS (
   SELECT ...
),
second_cte AS (
   SELECT ...
)
```